# I have a problem with form input and links

Tags: html, css

I don't have that much experience in HTML/CSS. As it says in the title, I have a problem with the input (where it says "What do you think about ?"). I left click on input field so I can write something inside it but when I click the submit logo it is not clickable. And the other problem is with Create account. It is not recognized as a link. The other links work but this one doesn't. It is also not clickable. After I added more CSS code those problems appeared.
Can someone help me with this problem?

P.S : This is a project for a non-programmer friend.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: url(images/backgroundWallpaper.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "myFont";
    src: url("fonts/coolvetica\ rg.ttf")
}



/* ************************************ HOME PAGE ************************************ */

.header {
    background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}

.searchbar {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 265px;
    bottom: 63px;
}

#input {
    width: 750px;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#searchbarBtn {
    position: relative;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    font-size: 21px;
    top: 2px;
}

#loginBtn {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1140px;
    bottom: 95px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.logoImg {
    width: 240px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.viewCart {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1370px;
    bottom: 128px;
}

.cartBtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

nav {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 37px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    word-spacing: 15px;
}

.navBtn {
    font-size: 17px;
}

header {
    background: url(images/headerWallpaper.jpg) center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.main {
    padding: 0px 130px;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "myFont";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Danube</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="header">
            <img class="logoImg" src="images/logo.png">
            <div class="searchbar">
                <form>
                    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="What do you think about ?" name="search">
                    <button id="searchbarBtn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBtn">Hello, <a href="pages/login.html">Create account</a></div>
            <div class="viewCart">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <a class="cartBtn" href="#">My Basket</a>
            </div>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <a class="navBtn" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="navBtn" href="#">Offers</a>
            <a class="navBtn" href="#">Products</a>
            <a class="navBtn" href="#">Showrooms</a>
            <a class="navBtn" href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="main">
            <header>

            </header>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div>S.C. DANUBE ROMANIA S.R.L. este inregistrata cu numarul 000 / 2022 in registrul de evidenta a prelucrarilor de date cu caracter personal</div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form is overlapped with other elements. that's why it is not clickable. adjust your CSS and both problems will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of problems with the code. Try avoiding fixed values like px for things. Keep your website responsive - you can use flex or something for maintaining a responsive layout.

It is easier to see the problem when you inspect it using Firefox's(or any other browsers) inspecting tool.

You can fix the problems you stated by implementing suggestions told by us here but they may break something else since we don't know the whole code.

Firstly, you can see that the `header` element is above the search bar and hence the search bar is unfocusable. You can either change the `z-index` of the `header` element to -1 or something or you can set the search bar's `z-index` to a bigger value.

The `Create Account` link has the same problem as well. In this case,the element with the viewCart class is overlapping the link. What you need to do is in it's style change the `padding-left` property to `margin-left` and it will stop overlapping.

Again, try to keep things simple by using a more dynamic way so that elements are positioned and sized automatically instead of you having to specify the sizes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

both are incorrectly positioned, they are pushing to the top and some element is overlapping over them.

I recreated your code by positioning them slightly lower using  `position: relative; top : 100px` and then input box was accepting clicks and create link was working.

````
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: url(images/backgroundWallpaper.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "myFont";
    src: url("fonts/coolvetica\ rg.ttf")
}



/* ************************************ HOME PAGE ************************************ */

.header {
    background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}

.searchbar {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 265px;
    bottom: 63px;
}

#input {
    width: 750px;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}

#searchbarBtn {
    position: relative;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    font-size: 21px;
    top: 2px;
}

#loginBtn {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1140px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.logoImg {
    width: 240px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.viewCart {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1370px;
    bottom: 128px;
}

.cartBtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

nav {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 37px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    word-spacing: 15px;
}

.navBtn {
    font-size: 17px;
}

header {
    background: url(images/headerWallpaper.jpg) center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.main {
    padding: 0px 130px;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "myFont";
}```

Please check the changes in #loginBtn and #input
````

Comment: Where did you put the position: relative and top: 100px ? Because I tried this and it is still the same. Edit: Nevermind found it. But I need them in that position.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, the button always have a default cursor, if you want to change the cursor to the pointer on hovering you must add this: `button:hover {cursor: pointer}`
2. Second of all, you're using positions wrongly and don't understand them. Read about positions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

I deleted all of the position relatives and *top & bottom*.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(images/backgroundWallpaper.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myFont";
  src: url("fonts/coolvetica\ rg.ttf")
}


/* ************************************ HOME PAGE ************************************ */

.header {
  background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
}

.searchbar {
  margin-left: 265px;
}

#input {
  width: 750px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#searchbarBtn {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

/* EDITED HERE */
#searchbarBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

#loginBtn {
  padding-left: 1140px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.logoImg {
  width: 240px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.viewCart {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1370px;
  bottom: 128px;
}

.cartBtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

nav {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 37px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  word-spacing: 15px;
}

.navBtn {
  font-size: 17px;
}

header {
  background: url(images/headerWallpaper.jpg) center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main {
  padding: 0px 130px;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(19, 25, 33);
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-family: "myFont";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Danube</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <img class="logoImg" src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="searchbar">
      <form>
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="What do you think about ?" name="search">
        <button id="searchbarBtn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="loginBtn">Hello, <a href="#">Create account</a></div>
    <div class="viewCart">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
      <a class="cartBtn" href="#">My Basket</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <nav>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#">Offers</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#">Products</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#">Showrooms</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="main">
    <header>

    </header>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div>S.C. DANUBE ROMANIA S.R.L. este inregistrata cu numarul 000 / 2022 in registrul de evidenta a prelucrarilor de date cu caracter personal</div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help man. Now I understand what I did wrong. Thank you very much and have a nice day !